# Join Two Table without Finding Match and Non Matching Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table structures are shown here:

**Table1**

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 20 |
| 20 |
| 40 |
| 50 |
| 60 |

**Table2**

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 30 |
| 40 |
| 60 |

My expected result is this:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | Matched |
| 20 | Not Matched |
| 20 | Not Matched |
| 30 | Not Matched |
| 40 | Matched |
| 50 | Not Matched |
| 60 | Matched |

Query I'm trying to use:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) rn
    FROM Table1
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) rn
    FROM Table2
)
SELECT T1.Col1,
    CASE WHEN T2.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Matched' ELSE 'NotMatched' END AS Col2
FROM cte1 T1
LEFT JOIN cte2 T2
    ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND T1.rn = T2.rn
ORDER BY T1.Col1, T2.Col1 DESC;
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your query???

Answer (score 1):

You are halfway there. To identify matches and mismatches from either side of the join, you need to perform a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and the check for both `T1.Col1 IS NOT NULL AND T2.Col1 IS NOT NULL` in your `CASE` expression. To include `Col1` in your results for all cases, you can use `ISNULL(T1.Col1, T2.Col1) AS Col1`.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) rn
    FROM Table1
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) rn
    FROM Table2
)
SELECT
    ISNULL(T1.Col1, T2.Col1) AS Col1,
    ISNULL(T1.rn, T2.rn) AS rn,
    CASE WHEN T1.Col1 IS NOT NULL AND T2.Col1 IS NOT NULL
        THEN 'Matched'
        ELSE 'NotMatched'
        END AS Col2
FROM cte1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN cte2 T2
    ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND T1.rn = T2.rn
ORDER BY Col1, rn
```

Results:

| Col1 | rn | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 1 | Matched |
| 20 | 2 | NotMatched |
| 20 | 3 | NotMatched |
| 30 | 1 | NotMatched |
| 40 | 1 | Matched |
| 50 | 1 | NotMatched |
| 60 | 1 | Matched |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-KPJULnS).

Comment: `COALESCE` isn't available on the completely unsupported SQL Server 2008; it was added in  SQL Server 2012 (also now completely unsupported).

Comment: @ThomA Thanks for the catch. (db<>fiddle does not go back that far, so I could not test that version.) For the two-valued case, `ISNULL()` can be used with identical behavior.  (I usually prefer to use `COALESCE()` when picking values from `OUTER JOIN`ed tables, because it scales up beyond the 2-table case.) I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select t1.col1,
    case (select count(1) from cte2 t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.rn = t1.rn)
    when 1 then 'Matched'
    else 'Not matched'
    end as col2
from cte1 t1
union 
select t2.col1, 'Not matched' from cte2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from cte1 t1 where t1.col1 = t2.col1);
```

Returns

```
20  Matched
20  Not matched
30  Not matched
40  Matched
50  Not matched
60  Matched
```

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation in addition to a working solution.